# Duplicate Typhoon assemblies from normal and test target when activating

Tags: ios, typhoon

I want to write tests for assemblies themselves to make sure that I didn't tell the assembly to inject a property which does not exist (any more) in the class that is injected. Since this results in an error at runtime I want to make sure that the assembly can inject e.g. a view controller correctly without having to navigate to the view controller manually in the app to test it.

I have a mixed set of assemblies written in Objective-C and Swift.
A simple test looks like this:
Obj-C:

```
@interface ViewControllerAssemblyTests : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerAssembly *sut;
@end
@implementation ViewControllerAssemblyTests
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    self.sut = [ViewControllerAssembly new];
    [self.sut activate];
}
- (void)testInstantiateSignInViewController {
    // When
    SignInViewController *vc = [self.sut signInViewController];
    // Then
    XCTAssertNotNil(vc.alertService);
}
@end
```

Swift:

```
class ViewControllerAssemblyTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut: ViewControllerAssembly!
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        self.sut = ViewControllerAssembly()
        self.sut.activate()
    }
    func testExample() {
        // When
        let vc = self.sut.signInViewController() as! SignInViewController
        // Then
        XCTAssertNotNil(vc.alertService)
    }
}
```

Running the test written in Objective-C works just fine. The test written in The Swift test however fails when activating the assembly: `Key '...' is already registered`.
I found that the `TyphoonCollaboratingAssembliesCollector` finds assemblies written in Swift twice - once in the app target, and once again in the test target, which results in the above error when trying to register the assemblies' keys.

It all boils down to the type of the `inspectedClass` parameter for the method `collaboratingAssembliesForClass:withCollaboratorClasses:` which is the correct assembly from the app target when running the Obj-C test, but it's the wrong assembly from the test target when running the Swift test. I added the assemblies to both targets obviously, to be able to access them in the tests.

My current workaround is to simply write the tests in Obj-C, but is there a solution so I can write the tests in Swift?

Comment: I generally advise people to write an integration test for the _object being produced_ by Typhoon, rather than the assemblies. All being well here indicates that the assembly instructions are correct. However, if you wish you can write tests for the assemblies themselves - some folks do this too. As for the exact problem here, not quite sure - will wait for some Typhoon+Swift users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had a look at this page on [integration testing](https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon/wiki/integration-testing). Is that what you mean? As I understood it, patching out an assembly means that the assembly simply returns my mock instead of allocating and injecting a new instance, right? Can you give me an example how you would do it?

Comment: No need for patcher here - just test the component being produced by Typhoon. Patcher is for when you want an integration test (real components) but need to patch one underlying component, in order to put the system in a required state for the test run, or to avoid an undesired side effect of the test.